# Flutter syncfusion maps - tweak placement of dataLabels

Tags: flutter, dart, maps, geojson, syncfusion

Is it possible to change the alignment or placement of the `dataLabels` while using the `syncfusion_flutter_maps` package? For the most part they are centered, but this example where Florida is on the border of land and sea is not ideal. I've explored `MapDataLabelSettings` and `SfMapsThemeData` and `TextStyle` and overflow is pretty much the extend of customizability around the appearance of the dataLabels.

[image]

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.

Answer (score 1):

The data label placement in the [MapShapLayer](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_maps/latest/maps/MapShapeLayer-class.html) used the centered polygon logic only and the shape of the Florida polygon is not in the proper position. So you can achieve your requirement with the help of [markerBuilder](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_maps/latest/maps/MapLayer/markerBuilder.html) and [initialMarkersCount](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_maps/latest/maps/MapLayer/initialMarkersCount.html) property in the map, by setting the data label value of Florida to an empty string and rendering a custom marker in that location with the help of latitude and longitude value of Florida. It will render a text widget with the string `FL` in the center. We have shared the code snippet below for your reference.

Code snippet:

```dart
SfMaps(
  layers: <MapLayer>[
    MapShapeLayer(
      loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
        return const SizedBox(
          height: 25,
          width: 25,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            strokeWidth: 3,
          ),
        );
      },
      initialMarkersCount: 1,
      markerBuilder: (context, index) {
        return const MapMarker(
            latitude: 27.6648,
            longitude: -81.5158,
            child: Text(
              'FL',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 9),
            ));
      },
      source: _mapSource,     
      showDataLabels: true,
      dataLabelSettings: const MapDataLabelSettings(
        overflowMode: MapLabelOverflow.hide,
        textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 9),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's a great solution, though I need to use markerBuilder and initialMarkersCount for other things, so can't hold them up for this fix. Appreciate it though and perhaps this will help someone else!